# getElementsByClassName and …ByTagName, <path> and <svg>, using onclick="" to change styles

Tags: javascript, css, svg, onclick

hope my question is up to par (I researched this all morning so I hope i was thorough enough)

I'm learning all this new html5, so I can make interactive drawings using SVG, `<canvas>` and CSS3 using a bit of Javascript. I'm trying to get rid of the ugly, redundant functions I had doing things, and tidy up my coding nicely.

I'm having a problem with creating the javascript for a `<button>`'s onclick event to change style for a class which contains all the paths in an SVG using `document.getElementsByClassName`. 
   I already have it working with `document.getElementById`, but I want to affect multiple paths at once without having to waste lots of lines full of grabbing hundreds of IDs into a var or something like that.

Here's my code so far, the first button works, the next two are what I'm having trouble with.

```
<head>
<style>
  .pathclass { 
fill:none;
stroke:#ffffff;
stroke-width:4; }
</style></head>

<body>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('pathId').style.stroke = '#000000';" />
<br />
<button onclick="document.getElementsByClassName('pathClass').style.stroke = '#000000';" />
<br />
<button onclick="document.getElementsByTagName('path').style.stroke = '#000000';" />

<svg><g><path id="pathId" class="pathclass" /></g></svg>
```

Next, I'd like to set all the `classNames` automatcally using something like `document.getElementsTagName('path').className = 'pathclass'`

Comment: document.querySelector and document.querySelectorAll

Comment: Thanks Geuis. I looked that up but it says it only returns the first single element that matches the selectors. I'm looking for a way to select all the elements that have that same class at once.

Comment: @Geuis does this function similarly to the `d3.selectAll` mentioned in @Duopixel's answer?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.yourclass'); //returns array containing all elements. I mentioned both so you could learn both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `document.getElementsByClassName` it returns a NodeList. A NodeList is similar to an array, and you have to iterate through it in order to apply a style:

```
// collect all nodes with class='oldclass'
var nodes = document.getElementsByClassName('oldclass');
// loops to get each node in our NodeList
for (var i=0, length = nodes.length; i < length; i++) {
   // i starts at 0 and increments with each loop (i++ increments i on each iteration)
   // it won't stop until it reaches the number of nodes (i < length)
   // so on the first iteration it will be nodes[0]
   // which is your first element, the second time
   // it will be nodes[1] which is your second, and so on
   nodes[i].style.stroke = "black";
}

var paths = document.getElementsByTagName('path');
for (var i=0, length = paths.length; i < length; i++) {
   paths[i].className = "newclass";
}
```

Now, this is pretty cumbersome, and that's where javascript libraries come into play. I would recommend [D3.js](http://d3js.org) as it works great with SVG. With D3 the equivalent code would be:

```
d3.selectAll(".oldclass").style("stroke", "black");
d3.selectAll("path").attr("class", "newclass");
```

Comment: right on, that looks like the answer right there! Now all I have to do is understand it XD. This is assuming all the paths are: 1) not in a separate document; 2) labeled class="pathClass" already, right?

Comment: Perfect, now my question is, how can i use this same setup to perform the `nodes[i].className = "newclass"` part beforehand, using `document.getElementsByTagName('path')`